# Where to import pool.js file in my project file structure

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pooling

I am currently working on my e-commerce project in node js, here is my project file structure-

````
public
    - assets
      - js/
      - css/
      - images/
views
    - index.ejs
    - login.ejs
config/
    - pool.js
router/
    - login.js
    - index.js
    - signup.js
app.js
.env   

Here is the code for the **pool.js** file:

```   
     require('dotenv').config();
     const mysql = require('mysql')
     
     // pool  connection 
     const pool = mysql.createPool({
             host     : process.env.DB_HOST,
             user     : process.env.DB_USER,
             password : process.env.DB_PASS,
             database : process.env.DB_NAME
     })
    
     pool.on('enqueue', (connection)=>{
            console.log('Enqueue Event Triggred')
     })
     pool.on('acquire', (connection)=>{
            console.log('connection acquired with threatId: ' + connection.threadId)
     })
     module.exports = pool;
```
````

and here is my router/login.js file:

```
    const express = require('express')
    const router = express.Router()
    const pool = require('../config/pool')
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser') 
    const urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })

router.post('/', urlencodedParser, (req, res, next)=>{
    pool.getConnection(...)
})
```

My main question is where to import the **pool.js** file that can be accessible to the all routers file. And what if my code for the pool.js file is replaced by the ***pool cluster connection code***, any error??

Comment: You can create controllers for each route and use the pool there (unless it is a transaction). Or directly import them in your routers ie login.js etc